Optimizar juego de piedra-papel-tijera
Estoy empezando a aprender a programar y como primer ejercicio hecho, sin ver tutoriales ni nada, realicé un piedra, papel o tijera. Pero, ¿cómo puedo mejorarlo? O en su caso, ¿qué es lo que está mal?
Aunque el código funciona, tengo la sensación de que está muy largo y podría mejorarlo, pero no sé cómo.
# JUEGO DE PIEDRA, PAPEL O TIJERA
import random

while True:
    entrada = int(input('''Escoge una opción:
Piedra (1)
Papel (2)
Tijera (3) : '''))

    computadora = random.randint(1, 3)
    
    if entrada == 1:
        entrada_opcion = "Piedra"
    elif entrada == 2:
        entrada_opcion = "Papel"
    else:
        entrada_opcion = "Tijera"
    
    if computadora == 1:
        computadora_opcion = "Piedra"
    elif computadora == 2:
        computadora_opcion = "Papel"
    else:
        computadora_opcion = "Tijera" 

    if entrada == 1 and computadora == 2:
        print("PERDISTE, escogiste piedra y la compitadora papel")
    elif entrada == 2 and computadora == 3:
        print("PERDISTE, escogiste papel y la computadora tijera")
    elif entrada == 3 and computadora == 1:
        print("PERDISTE, escogiste tijera y la computadora piedra")
    elif entrada == computadora:
        print("Fue un empate, vuelve a intentarlo")
        continue    
    else:
        print(f"Has GANADO, escogiste {entrada_opcion} y la computadora escogió {computadora_opcion}")
    
    volver_a_jugar = input("¿Quieres volver a jugar? ('si/no'): ")
    if volver_a_jugar.lower() != "si":
        break
print("Gracias por jugar :)")


Me parece extraño que esta pregunta no haya sido cerrada por ser basada en opiniones ya... no hay problema, se está pidiendo un consejo.

En lugar de while True y terminar con un if ... break, puedes usar while volver_a_jugar

Una mejor alternativa es tener un arreglo (lista) que te diga que elemento le gana a otro. Para simplificarlo, los vamos a numerar a partir de cero. Entonces

0 (Piedra) gana a 2 (Tijera).
1 (Papel) le gana a 0 (Piedra).
2 (Tijera) le gana a 1 (Papel)

Lo puedo resumir en esta lista:
sig = [2, 0, 1]

O sea, tomo la elección del jugador y la uso como indice para extraer la opción a quien le gana. Si el jugador elige Piedra (0), el elemento sig[0] me dice que le gana a 2 (Tijeras).
Para resolver una jugada, primero veo si el jugador le gana a la computadora. En caso contrario, veo si la computadora gana. Si no, es empate.
Para completar, en lugar de operar con 1, 2, 3, trabajaremos con 0, 1, 2, de modo de poder usar el valor como índice.
Con eso el código se reduce a:
# JUEGO DE PIEDRA, PAPEL O TIJERA

import random

sig = [2, 0, 1]
nom = ['piedra', 'papel', 'tijera']

while True:
    entrada = int(input('''Escoge una opción: Piedra (1) Papel (2) Tijera (3) terminar (0) : '''))
    if entrada == 0:
        break
    entrada -= 1
    computadora = random.randint(0, 2)

    print(f"Computadora eligio {nom[computadora]}")
    if sig[entrada] == computadora:
        print("ganaste")
    elif sig[computadora] == entrada:
        print("perdiste")
    else:
        print("Fue un empate, vuelve a intentarlo")

print("Gracias por jugar :)")


El usuario ya tiene en cuenta los casos en los que gana, ya están cubiertos en el else.

@Jakala. Oh, si. Tienes razón.

JUEGO DE PIEDRA, PAPEL O TIJERA REFACTORIZADO
import random

      # Si hay código repetido, creo una función que lo ejecute:    
def getEleccion( numero ):
    if numero == 1:
       return "Piedra"
    if numero == 2:
       return "Papel"
    if numero == 3:
       return "Tijera"
    
while True: 
    entrada = int( input( '''Escoge una opción: Piedra (1) Papel (2) Tijera (3) : ''' ))
        
    computadora = random.randint( 1, 3 )
    
      # trato de evitar crear variables que "viven solo una linea" 
      # entrada_opcion = getEleccion( entrada )
      # computadora_opcion = getEleccion( computadora )
    print( f"Escogiste {getEleccion( entrada )} y la computadora {getEleccion( computadora )}" )

          # si tenemos varios "if" que conducen a Roma, los agrupamos
    if entrada == computadora:
       print( "Fue un empate, vuelve a intentarlo" )
       
    elif entrada == 1 and computadora == 2 or entrada == 2 and computadora == 3 or entrada == 3 and computadora == 1:
       print( "PERDISTE" )

    else:
       print( "Has GANADO" )
       
      # trato de evitar crear variables que "viven solo una linea" 
    if input( "¿Quieres volver a jugar? ( 'si/no' ): ").lower() != "si":
       break
    
print( "Gracias por jugar :)" )

Claro que también podemos simplificar la obtención del resultado:
resta = entrada - computadora
if resta == 0:
    print( "Empate" )
elif resta == 1 or resta == -2:
    print( "Ganaste" )
else:
    print( "Perdiste" )
print( resta )

Gracias a @Cram245, se puede resumir el elif así:
elif resta % 3 == 1:
    print( "Ganaste" )


def getEleccion(num): return ['Piedra', 'Papel', 'Tijera'][num-1] es la forma pythonica.

Solo por añadir un pequeño comentario, el elif de la simplificación de la obtención del resultado se puede compactar más con resta % 3 == 1. Además, pondria en el if y el elif los casos de ganar y perder y en el else el de empate, pero eso ya son manias personales.
Supongo que sera una errata pero el último print deberia ser print(resta)

@Cram245, corregido, muy buena la simplificación!!.
